# How to create a three.js Geometry from a JSON object WITHOUT using JSONLoader

Tags: three.js

I'm creating a scene where objects are brought in from JSON files (exported from blender) and added to the scene. Since this is going to be a Cordova app, I can't use JSONLoader (or any XHR resource).

I'm able to get the JSON file using the FileSystem API, but I can't figure out how to create a THREE.Geometry object from the JSON, since the Geometry constructor does not take any arguments. (normally, the finished Geometry object is provided automatically by the JSONLoader callback function). I can't help but feel there's something obvious I'm missing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can build your own `THREE.Geometry` object by manually adding its attributes. The docs give you [a quick example](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry) of how to add vertices and faces:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3( -10,  10, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( -10, -10, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3(  10, -10, 0 )
);

geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );

geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
```

With this example, you could write your own iterators, and create your Geometry with the data in your JSON file.

**Option 2:**

The above process is probably going to get too verbose if you need normals, uvs, colors, etc. So instead of re-writing it manually, just use the `JSONLoader`'s parsing attributes, without using it to load the data. This is possible via the [`THREE.JSONLoader.parse()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/JSONLoader.parse) method:

```
// Use whatever method you're using to fetch the data
var JSONData = getJSONSomehow(); 

// Now we only use JSONLoader for parsing 
var JSONParser = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var myObject3D = JSONParser.parse(JSONData);
scene.add(myObject3D);
```

Comment: Option two should be the proposed option.

Comment: The parse method did the trick, thanks. I knew there must have been something I was missing.

Is there a similar method I can use for TextureLoader? The FileSystem API only returns the encoded URL and not and image I can pass to the THREE.Texture contructor.

Comment: You'll need to create the image yourself: `var image = document.createElement('img'); image.src = encodedURL; var tex = new THREE.Texture(image);`